# Regular expression to allow only string and number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm making the pattern to check the user can only enter number and string.  Please anyone  can help me or give some reference.  Following is my code.  Thnks in advance.

```
NSString *regEx =
     @"(?:[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%\\&'*+/=?\\^_`{|}"
     @"~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\"
     @"x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-"
     @"z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5"
     @"]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-"
     @"9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21"
     @"-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";

NSString *strRoadworthyGet=@"vinod123";
NSPredicate *matchPattern =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",regEx];
BOOL resultMatch =[matchPattern evaluateWithObject:strRoadworthyGet];

if(!resultMatch)
  NSLog(@"invalid pattern");
```

Comment: May be you could format the code better. Moreover it would be nice to first know what is the logic you have put behind regEx. It seems to be cumbersomely long for the expression you require

Comment: This regex will match one or more letters and numbers only: `^[A-Za-z0-9]+$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSCharacterSet's [alphanumeric](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nscharacterset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/alphanumericCharacterSet) method to return check for Letters, Marks and Numbers.

If you want to go for RegularExpression, you can use

```
NSString *regEx = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
```

Answer (score 0):

[Defining legal input characters](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2009/01/defining-legal-input-character.html)